# How to calculate different passwords formed 6 lower case English letters in Python

Tags: python

Use Python to calculate how many different passwords can be formed with 6 lower case English letters.  For a 1 letter password, there would be 26 possibilities.  For a 2 letter password, each letter is independent of the other, so there would be 26 times 26 possibilities.  Using this information, print the amount of possible passwords that can be formed with 6 letters.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place for asking someone to do your home assignments. You need to at least show your effort towards solving the problem, posting some code that you've tried

Comment: it's a question on coursera.                      https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-crash-course/exam/Zcevo/module-1-graded-assessment/attempt?redirectToCover=true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each letter has 26 possible choices, and the password needs to be of length 6, so there are `26 * 26 * 26 * 26 * 26 * 26`, or `26**6` possible passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Given there are 26 lowercase letters and a password of length `n`, then you have 26 choices per character and so for a password n units long you have 26^n choices.

You can use [this](https://www.dcode.fr/permutations-generator) website to see all the possible permutations.

Here is a useful diagram to visualize the above problem by assuming the English alphabet only has three letters `A`, `B` and `C` and you want to pick a password of length 2:
[image]

Comment: Given that this is most likely a homework question, it would be in the student's best interest that you provide guidance rather than an answer with no explanation.

Comment: @EwanBrown I have changed my answer accordingly...

Comment: But that graph is off-topic, and has nothing to do not only with the question, but even with you answer. That graph illustrate the possible permutations of letters in a word. This is not the question. You can see, btw, that your answer, for a 3 letter words would be s³, s being the size of the alphabet, so, apparently 3³=27. How a tree leading to 6 words relate to that? A tree that does not contain AAA, AAB, AAC, ...

Comment: @chrslg Yeah you're right the previous graph was wrong, sorry I should've paid more attention. I have corrected it with a better graph, I am sure this one isn't wrong but correct me if it is, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
alphabet = 26
letters_in_word = int(input("Enter the number of letters should be in the 
password : "))
no_of_possibilities = alphabet**letters_in_word
print("No.of possible passwords formed with 6 letters are : 
",no_of_possibilities)
```

Explanation:

- As the alphabet length is 26, take a variable and assign 26 to it.
- Take the length of the password from the user.
- As it is given that each letter is independent from the other, repetitions are clearly allowed.
- So, each block of n letter word can be filled with any of 26 letters i.e., 26 choices.
- In such case, n blanks can be filled in 26x26x26x26x26x26....x26 ways. Simply in 26ⁿ ways.
- As n=6, result will be 26⁶, which is equal to 308915776.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, let us try to reason about it this way: for each letter, there are 26 possible outcomes. Therefore, we will raise 26 to the power of six since we have six letters.

Here is the script for the possible number of passwords:

Print (26**6) and run the script using any Python interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

```
alpate = 26

letters = int(input("your number of letters = "))

possible_passwords = alpate**letters

No_passwords = ('possible passwords that can be formed with ' + str(letters) + 'is ' + str(possible_passwords))

print(No_passwords)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Please don't write code for users if they don't provide their own attempt. We're not here to do people's homework (or job) for them. We're here to help them _learn_ and providing code to blindly copy and paste doesn't help with that. Additionally, two other users already explained how OP can solve this themselves six months ago.

Answer (score -1):

alphabets = 26

letters = 6

possible_passwords = alphabets**letters

No_of_passwords = ('possible passwords that can be formed with ' + str(letters) + 'is ' + str(possible_passwords))

print(No_of_passwords)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the most streamlined answer to the question:

password = (26**6)

print(password)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).